# Is there a specific term for denoting samples that are used in a test of independence?

Tags: chi-squared-test, terminology, sample

I know that there are independent samples and paired samples (paired samples is a special case of dependent samples of equal size).

In any test of independence we have a pair of random variables $(X,Y)$ that generated $n$ independent pairs $(X_1,Y_1), \ldots, (X_n,Y_n)$, so that $X_1,\ldots,X_n \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} F_X, ~ Y_1,\ldots,Y_n \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} F_Y$, where $F_X$ and $F_Y$ are unknown distributions of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Samples $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ and $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$ can be dependent or independent (as two random vectors; we use some test of independence to find out this). Is there a specific term for denoting this pair of samples?

Comment: These are paired samples.  You initial characterization of paired samples is not quite correct: the concept does not include any notion of dependence or independence, nor even of randomness.

Comment: @whuber Hmm, in the Internet there are a lot of websites which use word "paired" as a synonym for "dependent", for example, [this](https://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/gerstman/StatPrimer/paired.pdf). If these websites are wrong, then I am a bit confused – when we choose between Student's t-test for independent samples and Student's t-test for paired samples, does this mean that the latter test can be applied for "independent paired samples" as well as "dependent paired samples"?

Comment: Absolutely!  (On the Internet, you get what you pay for...)  "Paired samples" describes *data.*  It can also be used in narrower contexts to describe a *probability model* for paired data, but even then it would be illogical to exclude the possibility of independence among the samples.  In that case, you wouldn't be able ever to reject the null hypothesis.